# Can anyone tell me why my web server cannot connect to a DB server?

Tags: mysql

`Can't connect to MYSQL server` error. The DB is a separate server.
http://dpaste.com/99702/

I typed `nc dbserver 3306` and it returned:

```
[XXXXXX] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused
```

Even in my GRANT options, I specified `GRANT ALL TO *.* %...`

My friend said that the web server is being prevented from establishing a TCP connection of any kind to that port.

I checked `my.cnf`, nothing special there. Could it be because of my IP tables?

Comment: Systems administration -> Serverfault. Check your listen directive in my.cnf, and also do check iptables.

Comment: Just a general piece of advice: you may receive an answer quicker by posting on www.serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right.  The remote server refused the connection.  Either the MySQL server is not running, or something (a firewall?) is preventing the connection from going through.

Answer (score 0):

It could well be the case that the host on which `mysqld` is hosted is not allowing connections on the default `mysql` port `3306`. Also, additionally, you may want to ensure that `mysqld` is not running with the `--skip-networking` option, which sets `mysqld` to not listen for TCP/IP connections.